# concatenating arrays of strings using macro

Tags: c

I need to concatenate two arrays of string and need to call the function with that string

I have two arrays

```
char q[4] = {'t','e','s','t'};
char w[4] = {'f','u','n','c'};

#define dump(a,b)  a ## b
```

I have a function called

```
void testfunc()
{

...
..

}
```

if I call the macro dumb like
dumb(q,w) this is just concatenating q and w, i need to concatenate the strings in that array.

Need to call the function by concatenating the arrays of string using macros.
Is that possible??

Comment: `testfunc` doesn't appear to take any arguments?!

Comment: **Those aren't strings.**  Strings (in C) are NULL-terminated, meaning the last character will be `'\0'`, which you did not include.

Comment: do you want to use macros to expand to differnt function names? maybe you could use function pointers instead?

Comment: I just want to concatenate arrays of char.

Comment: why do you want to use a macro?

Comment: not necessarily macro..... I just want to call the function testfunc() which name is stored in two array char...

Answer (score 4):

No.  Macros don't understand C constructs (such as arrays), they just perform simple text substitution.

Answer (score 0):

> I just want to call the function testfunc() which name is stored in
>   two array char

Although you can't use macros in this case you could have an array for function pointers and select one you want to call at run time.

```
void (*p[NFUNCS])(void);
//...
p[0] = testfunc; /* store address of the function */
//...
(*p[0])(); // call to testfunc
```